# Angular promise (of a promise?). Or how do I chain a .then after an $http.success in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I got a service in Angular:

```
App.factory('AuthService', function ($q, $http, CredentialStorage) {
  var _endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000';
  return {
    login: function (credentials) {
      return $http
        .post('/api/users/login', credentials)
        .success(function (apiResult) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          if (apiResult.code == 0) { 
            $scope.user = apiResult.context;
            CredentialStorage.store(apiResult.context);
          }

          return deferred.promise;
        })
        .fail(function(apiResult, status, headers) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          return deferred.promise;
        });
    },
....});
```

Where I authenticate and store the user in some cookie or whatever (this is not relevant).

Then on my controller I got:

```
App.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, AuthService) {
    var _login = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        AuthService.login($scope.l).then(function() {
            alert('aaa');
            if (!AuthService.authenticatedUser) {
                $scope.errors = ['Invalid username and password. Please try again.'];
                alert($scope.errors);
            } else {
                alert('a' + $scope.errors);
            }
        })
    }
    $scope.login = _login;
});
```

For some reason my controller's then doesnt execute. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: What are those `var deferred = $q.defer();` supposed to do? You never resolve them.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can `return` from `success`/`fail` like you can from `then` callbacks.

Comment: ok - so clearly thats the problem. I just found out about promises and I m learning about them.

Comment: Where does `fail` come from? It's not part of angular's promise interface.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple answer is: you use `.then` which chains instead of `success` which just adds a listener:

```
App.factory('AuthService', function ($q, $http, CredentialStorage) {
  var _endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000';
  return {
    login: function (credentials) {
      return $http
        .post('/api/users/login', credentials)
        .then(function (response) {
          var apiResult = response.data;
          if (apiResult.code == 0) { 
              CredentialStorage.store(apiResult.context);
              return apiResult.context; // promises let you return the value
          }
          throw new Error("Authentication failed"); // return $q.reject
                                                    // if you don't want to invoke
                                                    // exceptionHandler
        });
    },
....});
```

Which would let you do:

```
   AuthService.login($scope.l).then(function(result) {
        $scope.user = result;
   }).catch(function(err){
        // code to handle the case authorization failed or the API call failed
   });
```

From Angular separation of concern's stand point, it is generally bad to modify UI scopes in a service/factory/provider. It's better to return the results.

Comment: There is a difference in the arguments of `success()` vs `then()`. So, instead of `then(function (apiResult){...` it should rather be `then(function(response){var apiResult = response.data;...`

Comment: You might also want to move that `return` statement after the `CredentialStorage.store()` call ;)

Comment: Haha, my head must have been someplace else